# Finding unused names in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I was curious if anyone would be able to help me or give me some direction. I have a worksheet with the following sort of data.

```
+---+----------------+--------+-----+----------------+
|   |       A        |   B    |  C  |       D        |
+---+----------------+--------+-----+----------------+
| 1 | Customer Names | Gender | DOB | Customer Names |
+---+----------------+--------+-----+----------------+
```

Etc.

So I wanted to know whether there's a way of being able to search `Column A` with a predefined list of customer names in `Column D`, then return the unused names in another column?

I tried the following code but it seems to be repeating the names that don't match. Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$3:$A$1999,MATCH(0,IFERROR(MATCH($A$3:$A$1999,$F$3:$F$399,0),COUNTIF($G$1:$G1,$A$3:$A$1999)),0)),"")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this formula in column E:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A1,D:D,0)),"",A1)
```